# The Value of Variables does not update inside components

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

When I put the input field inside a component, it doesn't update the value by any means. Is there something I've missed? Btw, I use Vue 3.

**Child Component (input-form.vue)**

```html
    <template>
      <input
        type="text"
        :value="searchField"
        @input="$emit('update:searchField', $event.target.value)"
      />
      <p>Text Inside: {{ searchField }}</p>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      emits: ["update:searchField"],
      props: {
        searchField: {
          type: String,
        },
      },
    };
    </script>
```

**Parent**

```html
    <template>
      <div>
        <input-form :searchField="searchField" />
        <p>Text Outside: {{ searchField }}</p>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import inputForm from "components/input-form.vue";
    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          searchField: "",
        };
      },
      components: {
        inputForm,
      },
    };
    </script>
```

Comment: Hey mate :), what do you want to achieve with input?

Comment: I want to get the data I type on the input field and pass it along from the child component to the parent. I made the input field a component in order to use it on other pages with the same style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not listening for the `update:searchField` event in the Parent.

```html
<input-form :searchField="searchField" @update:searchField="searchField = $event" />
```

or

```html
<input-form v-model:searchField="searchField" />
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. I forgot to add the listener.